# How to create custom rules in SonarQube for php?

Tags: php, sonarqube, rules

I need to add my own custom rules in sonarqube 6.0 for analyzing php code but didn't found any plugin(found but those are either deprecated or didn't worked). I want to add my own rules or change existing rules.

Answer (score 3):

To change existing rules, you'll need to either fork the plugin or provide pull requests (which may or may not be merged): https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-php

To simply add custom rules, there's a tutorial: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Custom+Rules+for+PHP

Comment: Is there any basic tutorial for building plugin to add new rules? The link of tutorial you provided is very high level and I'm very beginner in it. Thanks!

Comment: A low-level tutorial [exists for Java](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101) I'm going to guess that applying it to PHP would be frustrating